# How to invoke property editor upon double-clicking a TCollectionItem?

Tags: delphi, custom-component, design-time, propertyeditor

I have a custom control. It has a published property of type `TOwnedCollection`, which of course contains several instances of `TCollectionItem` (inherited to my own implementation). Let's call them `TMyComponent`, `TMyCollection`, and `TMyCollectionItem`.

Within `TMyCollectionItem`, I have a `TPersistent` property (let's call it `MyProp: TMyProp`), which also has a corresponding design-time editor installed into the IDE. All this works just fine, so when you're editing the collection, select a collection item, you can click the little button in the object inspector to invoke the property editor. All of this works fine.

What I would like to add is the ability to double-click the item within the collection editor to also invoke that very same property editor. However, I cannot find decent information how to do this. ChatGPT gave me code that simply didn't compile, probably because it was for much older versions of Delphi.

How do I implement the ability to double-click a `TMyCollectionItem` to invoke the property editor for `TMyCollectionItem.MyProp`?

NOTE: Looking into the source of `ColnEdit.pas` (for this collection editor), I see the `TListView` implements `OnClick`, but not `OnDblClick`, and so I'm questioning whether it's even possible to do what I want without rolling out my own collection editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE's *default* Collection Editor does not natively support the feature you are looking for.  As you noted:

> NOTE: Looking into the source of `ColnEdit.pas` (for this collection editor), I see the `TListView` implements `OnClick`, but not `OnDblClick`, and so I'm questioning whether it's even possible to do what I want without rolling out my own collection editor.

The default Collection Editor simply does not implement any logic when a `TListView` item is double-clicked on.

(BTW, it is not the `TListVew.OnClick` event that updates the Object Inspector, it is the `TListVew.OnChange` event that does.  That is the event that fires when ListView items are selected.)

However, all is not lost! There IS a way you can access the `TListView` of the default Collection Editor and assign your own `OnDblClick` event handler to it:

- Derive a new class from `ColnEdit.TCollectionEditor`, and have it assign an `OnDblClick` handler to the inherited `TListView`.
- Derive a new class from `ColnEdit.TCollectionProperty` and override its virtual `GetEditorClass()` method to return your `TCollectionEditor`-derived class type.
- Register your `TCollectionProperty`-derived class with [`DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) to override the default collection editor for your `TMyCollection` class.

Your derived Collection Editor can then invoke your `TMyProp` property editor when needed by using the [`DesignEditors.GetComponentProperties()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignEditors.GetComponentProperties) function:

- Use [`DesignIntf.CreateSelectionList()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.CreateSelectionList) to create a list and [`Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.IDesignerSelections.Add) the appropriate `TMyCollectionItem` object to it.
- Pass that list to `GetComponentProperties()`, along with a callback that will receive an `IPropertyEditor` for each property of the `TMyCollectionItem` object.
- When the callback sees your `TMyProp` property editor, it can call the editor's `Edit()` method.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Vcl.ComCtrls, DesignIntf, DesignEditors, System.TypInfo, ColnEdit;

type
  ...

  TMyCollectionEditor = class(TCollectionEditor)
  private
    procedure ListViewDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure InvokeMyPropEditor(const Prop: IProperty);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TMyCollectionProperty = class(TCollectionProperty)
  public
    function GetEditorClass: TCollectionEditorClass; override;
  end;

procedure Register;

...

constructor TMyCollectionEditor.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ListView1.OnDblClick := ListViewDblClick;
end;

procedure TMyCollectionEditor.ListViewDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
  Components: IDesignerSelections;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Selected;
  if Item = nil then Exit;
  Components := CreateSelectionList();
  Components.Add(Collection.Items[Item.Index]);
  GetComponentProperties(Components, [tkClass], Designer, InvokeMyPropEditor);
end;

procedure TMyCollectionEditor.InvokeMyPropEditor(const Prop: IProperty);
begin
  if Prop.GetPropType = typeinfo(TMyProp) then
    Prop.Edit;
end;

function TMyCollectionProperty.GetEditorClass: TCollectionEditorClass;
begin
  Result := TMyCollectionEditor;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('...', [TMyComponent]);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(typeinfo(TMyCollection), TMyComponent, '', TMyCollectionProperty);
  ...
end;
```

That being said, I did test this approach and while it DOES work functionally, there is a *slight* visual side effect - in 10.2.1 and later, the IDE's theming feature will no longer apply to your Collection Editor window when it is shown.  So, for instance, if you use a Dark theme in the IDE, the Collection Editor will not appear Dark anymore.

To fix this, you need to use the `IOTAIDEThemingServices` interface in the OpenTools API to register your `TCollectionEditor`-derived class so the IDE will theme it:

[Using IDE Styles in Third-Party Plugins](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_IDE_Styles_in_Third-Party_Plugins)

David Hoyle has also written an article on this topic:

[Theming OTA Forms](https://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/?p=2428)

For example:

```
uses
  ..., ToolsAPI;

type
  ...

  TMyCollectionEditor = class(TCollectionEditor)
  private
    FThemingService: IOTAIDEThemingServices;
    FThemingNotifier: Integer;
    ...
    procedure ThemeChanged;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TThemeChangedProc = procedure of object;

  TMyThemingNotifier = class(TInterfacedObject, IOTANotifier, INTAIDEThemingServicesNotifier)
  public
    OnThemeChanged: TThemeChangedProc;
    constructor Create(AProc: TThemeChangedProc);
    procedure AfterSave;
    procedure BeforeSave;
    procedure Destroyed;
    procedure Modified;
    procedure ChangingTheme;
    procedure ChangedTheme;
  end;

...

constructor TMyCollectionEditor.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...

  if Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAIDEThemingServices, FThemingService) then
  begin
    ThemeChanged;
    FThemingNotifier := FThemingService.AddNotifier(TMyThemingNotifier.Create(ThemeChanged) as INTAIDEThemingServicesNotifier);
  end;
end;

destructor TMyCollectionEditor.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FThemingService) then
    FThemingService.RemoveNotifier(FThemingNotifier);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMyCollectionEditor.ThemeChanged;
begin
  if FThemingService.IDEThemingEnabled then
  begin
    FThemingService.RegisterFormClass(TMyCollectionEditor);
    FThemingService.ApplyTheme(Self);
  end;
end;

constructor TMyThemingNotifier.Create(AProc: TThemeChangedProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  OnThemeChanged := AProc;
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.AfterSave;
begin
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.BeforeSave;
begin
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.Destroyed;
begin
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.Modified;
begin
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.ChangingTheme;
begin
end;

procedure TMyThemingNotifier.ChangedTheme;
begin
  if Assigned(OnThemeChanged) then
    OnThemeChanged();
end;
```

Despite Embarcadero's documentation saying the following (emphasis is mine):

> In your plugin initialization or your form’s constructor, call `IOTAIDEThemingServices.RegisterFormClass` with the class of your form, that is, the form type. **You only need to do this once to apply the style hooks to your form.** You do not need to unregister it.

I find that if `RegisterFormClass()` is not called again before `ApplyStyle()` after a Theme change, then `ApplyStyle()` DOES NOT apply the new theme correctly! As-if the IDE lost the previous Form class registration during the Theme change (IDE bug? I have reported it: [RSP-43972](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-43972)). Calling `RegisterFormClass()` before each call to `ApplyStyle()` works.

I also noticed that the default `TCollectionEditor` does not react to IDE Theme changes at all (definitely an IDE bug, which I have reported: [RSP-43971](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-43971)).

Comment: Hmm, I'm honestly not a fan of dirty hacks, especially as I'm trying to write a whole library of custom controls. I guess my answer is what I feared - I'll just go ahead and write my own collection editor.

Comment: @JerryDodge I posted an update that may help you

Comment: Awesome, seems much less dirty. I'll give it a try when I get the time. Cheers!

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm testing it right now, and it looks viable! I'll post an update when I'm done

Comment: @JerryDodge updated, with code.

Comment: Entirely outside the scope of my original question... I'm curious what would be involved to implement double-clicking on these collection items from within the IDE's "Structure" panel...

Comment: @JerryDodge sorry, that I have no clue about. That would warrant a separate post of its own, but I doubt you'll get an answer as that request is way out in left field for typical component development. As I mentioned earlier, you *might* be able to hack into the IDE UI with the OpenTools API, but I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: Indeed, not expecting an answer. Just curiosity.

Comment: @JerryDodge some of [David Hoyle's IDE/OTA projects](https://github.com/DGH2112) look like they might be useful in your journey.

Comment: I assume that in the `RegisterPropertyEditor` call, if I change `TMyComponent` to `nil`, it should work with any and all places where I implement `TMyCollection`, correct?

Comment: @JerryDodge don't assume, [read the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) ;-) But yes.

Comment: @JerryDodge I have added more information to my answer regarding IDE theming